# Use Angular ng-repeat to iterate over multi-tiered array

Tags: javascript, angularjs, arrays

I am struggling to get an array to appear how I would like.

I have:

```
$scope.array = [["one", "two", "three", "four"], "five"],["six", "seven", "three", "four"], "two"]];
```

And I want to iterate through and display the strings in the first array. I would like to display:

one two three four
six seven three four

Currently I have the below:

`<p ng-repeat="a in array">{{a[0]}}</p>`

But it is coming out as:

```
["one", "two", "three", "four"]

["six", "seven", "three", "four"]
```

I've tried a filter to remove the quotes etc, but it keeps pulling up the other array.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try like this

```
<div ng-repeat="item in array">
  <div ng-repeat="a in item[0]">
    {{a}}
    </div>
</div>
```

and the array should be like this

```
 $scope.array =
 [
   [["one", "two", "three", "four"], "five"],
   [["six", "seven", "three", "four"], "two"]
 ];
```

```js
var app = angular.module('app', []);
app.controller('main', ['$scope', function($scope) {
  $scope.array = [
    [
      ["one", "two", "three", "four"], "five"
    ],
    [
      ["six", "seven", "three", "four"], "two"
    ]
  ];
}]);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.23/angular.min.js"></script>
<div ng-app="app" ng-controller=main>
  <div ng-repeat="item in array">
    <div ng-repeat="a in item[0]">
      {{a}}
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: you got it first :)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried this and I'm getting the whole array showing. ie ["one", "two", "three", "four"], "five"

Comment: @Vinoth, Hi Sorry I don't know _node.js_ .